# When creating a addMemberToRole I get this error: ReferenceError: mesage is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error, discord, discord.js

When im coding the part of the discord bot that gives a role when activated i keep getting this error and im not sure if there is a bug i dont see but if you see it pls help me correct it!

**Error message.**

```
 if(mesage.content.startsWith(prefix + "prune")){
    ^

ReferenceError: mesage is not defined
```

**Section of script with problem.**

```
 if(mesage.content.startsWith(prefix + "prune")){
  let args = Message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
  let author = Message.member;
  let role = message.guilds.roles.find('name', "Moderator");
  if(author.roles.has(role.id)){
    if(!args[0]){
        Message.delete();
        Message.author.send("No arguments given.");
        return;
    }

  }  

}
```

**Full Script**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Discord.Client
const prefix = "/";

Client.on('ready', ()=>{
        console.log('Bot is online.');
})

Client.on('message', (Message)=>{
    if(!Message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    if(Message.content.startsWith(prefix + "hello")){
        Message.channel.send("Hello.");

    }

    if(Message.content.startsWith(prefix + "help")){
        Message.channel.send("The only avaible command right now is /help and /hello.")
        Message.author.send("This is only for test purposes!");
    }

    if(mesage.content.startsWith(prefix + "prune")){
      let args = Message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
      let author = Message.member;
      let role = message.guilds.roles.find('name', "Moderator");
      if(author.roles.has(role.id)){
        if(!args[0]){
            Message.delete();
            Message.author.send("No arguments given.");
            return;
         }

      }  

    }


})


Client.login("<Bot Token>");
```

Comment: hint, your code refers to `mesage` and `message` and `Message`

Comment: Isn't it a typo? I mean, in place of `message` it should be `Message`

Comment: Every letter counts, especially the ones that are important. Double-check your spelling. If you're still stumped, copy-paste the original spelling. We all have days where a single letter bug escapes us.

Answer (score 0):

All your code refers to `Message`, except this line which is `mesage`, not only mis-spelled, but incorrectly lower-case.

Making that consistent with the other things should fix the issue.

> Note that JavaScript generally reserves capital letters for things like classes, lower-case for variables and arguments. As you can see here the syntax highlighter thinks this is a class and is colouring it accordingly. Lower-case `message` is the conventional argument name.

Comment: `let role = Message.guilds.roles.find('name', "Moderator");
                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`  **I still get this error**

Comment: One problem at a time. That implies `Message.guilds` is undefined, so figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Change `mesage` (the typo) with `message` (not uppercase). Make sure to also change `Message` with `message` (again, no uppercase)